# Efficient strategies for retrying AdMob ad loading with an app-wide frequency cap

Tags: java, android, admob

I am integrating AdMob into my Android application, where I have set an app-wide frequency cap to limit ad impressions within a certain timeframe.

I'm currently facing a challenge when trying to handle retries for ad loading once this cap is reached. My initial thought was to use polling to periodically attempt to load the ad, but I'm worried this could potentially harm the performance of my app due to the constant checks.

Is polling the only viable method to retry loading ads after the frequency cap is hit, or are there other recommended approaches to handle this situation?

Ideally, I'd like an efficient solution that respects the frequency cap set on the AdMob console, and doesn't result in excessive ad requests or overuse of system resources.

I would appreciate any advice or insights into the best practices for managing ad loading and retry mechanisms in AdMob when an app-wide frequency cap is in place.

Additional details:

AdMob SDK version: 21.5.0

Platform: Android

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: If the cap is reached, all the retry efforts for the specified time will not return an Ad & will fail with a callback value of `Frequency cap reached`, so a single retry should be enough. What exactly are you trying to achieve on cap reach here?

Comment: If single try, it won't reload the ad after the cap expired. Also, we can't get the cap from admob in app. Duration is needed to be hard coded. This makes the settings in admob useless unless stupid polling.

Comment: `If single try, it won't reload the ad after the cap expired` - Correct & intended behaviour but retries would also not load the Ads until the cap is complete. You surely cannot get the cap settings from Admob but you can indeed use `RemoteConfig` for this. The downside is that you'll have to manually update RC's value every-time you set/change a new cap.